# number that start with 2 digits in form validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I tried with substract to 'pick up' the 2 digits but it does not work ,'boleta' have to start with '20',else is show the message "Introduce solo los 10 digitos de tu Boleta!".

thanks!

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nombreErr = $boletaErr = "";
$nombre = $boleta =  "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if (empty($_POST["boleta"])){
$boletaErr = "Boleta is required";
}
else{
$boleta = test_input($_POST["boleta"]);
$boletavalida=substr($boleta,0,2); 
//check if boleta only contains numbers
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && !$boletavalida ==20){
$boletaErr="Introduce solo los 10 digitos de tu Boleta!";
}   
}
}

function test_input($data){
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: try this: `if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && $boletavalida != 20){`

Comment: I may be incorrect here - but I believe by using `substr(...)` you are creating a string not an integer. either use `$integer = (int) $string;` to convert the string to an integer or try `&& !$boletavalida == '20'`

Comment: @Justice, he wants 10 digits long and it must start with `20`. Check my answer please.

Comment: @edvinas.me I know - however his regex for 10 characters long part has no issues that I personally can see myself :)
From what I understood, the OP was asking for matching the starting '20' - this is what I answered.

Answer (score 1):

This following line is incorrect:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && !$boletavalida == 20) {
```

You are negating the value of `$boletavalida` when instead, you really mean "is not equal to" which should be using the `!=` operator.

Try the below:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && $boletavalida != '20') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && !$boletavalida ==20){
```

To this:

```
if ((!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $boleta) && (strpos($boletavalida, '20') != 0)){
```